# Asp.net go to previous page

Tags: asp.net

I have 5 dropdownlist in asp.net.User selects 5 dropdownlist after that click to button.Button sends page to another page.If i go previous page dropdownlist selectedvalues and datas lose(it displays default values without selected values)

I tried below

```
Response.Redirect("PreviousPage.aspx");
```

datas losing is there any solution ?

Comment: You would need to store the values somewhere and re-populate the controls with the stored values when `PreviousPage.aspx` loads.  Storing them in session state is commonly done for something like this.  So you might store the selected drop-down value in a session key, redirect as needed, and in `Page_Load` on the desired page check for a stored session value to use to pre-populate the drop-down.

Comment: I disagree, this can be accomplished without manually populating session.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Response.Redirect()`, you can change the `PostBackUrl` of the button to the target page, or use `Server.Transfer()`. Once there you should be able to access the properties you need from the `Page.PreviousPage` object.

Example using Server.Transfer:

Page1.aspx.cs:

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx");
}
```

Page2.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var addressDropdownSelectedValue = ((Page1)Page).PreviousPage.AddressDropdown.SelectedItem.Value; //or SelectedValue
}
```

Comment: It's the same as `Response.Redirect()`. Just `Server.Transfer("PreviousPage.aspx");`

Comment: do i need to write it on load of next page ?

Comment: no, `Server.Transfer` should be used instead of `Response.Redirect`. Added example.

Answer (score 0):

With the ScriptManager in the AJAX control toolkit (you get this in 4.0+, I think maybe even in 3.5), you can add history points. You add a history point and use that value to rebuild the page state.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488548%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

You can also strongly type the previous page if you want to grab values from it. You do this with `<%@ PreviousPage  %>` directive. Then in code you could use `Page.PreviousPage.FindControl`

Comment: The PreviousPage property will be null, even if it's strongly-typed, if you use Response.Redirect though.